# Delegate returns nil and not being called

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, overlay, delegation

I have an overlay that I want to remove when a `button` is clicked thereby dismissing the `ViewController`. I have debugged and the `delegate` is currently returning nil. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Have I missed implementing something else? I have even tried out print statements but can't see anything.

```
protocol DismissOverlayDelegate: class {
    func dismissOverlay(_ sender: PlayersViewController)
}

class PlayersViewController: UIViewController {

    weak var delegate: DismissOverlayDelegate?

    @IBAction func getStartedTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.delegate?.dismissOverlay(self)
    }
}
```

and in my `ViewController` where I implement the `delegate` method

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController, DismissOverlayDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var customOverlay: CustomOverlayView!

    let playersViewController = PlayersViewController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.playersViewController.delegate = self
    }

    func dismissOverlay(_ sender: PlayersViewController) {
        self.customOverlay.removeFromView()
    }
}
```

> > delegate = (DismissOverlayDelegate?)  nil

The PlayersViewController is embedded into a UIPageViewController

```
class HomeViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

    var pages = [UIViewController]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        for storyboardIDs in ["playersVC1","playersVC2"] {
            let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: storyboardIDs)
            self.pages.append(viewController!)
        }
        self.dataSource = self
        self.setViewControllers([self.pages.first!], direction: .forward, animated: true)
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        let currentIndex = self.pages.firstIndex(of: viewController)!
        if currentIndex > 0 {
            return self.pages[currentIndex - 1]
        }
        return nil
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        let currentIndex = self.pages.firstIndex(of: viewController)!
        if currentIndex < (self.pages.count - 1) {
            return self.pages[currentIndex + 1]
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: your instance `playersViewController` is not the instance that is on-screen, you need to get hold of the actual instance in the view controller stack. You cannot just create an instance using `PlayersViewController()`.

Comment: how are you using `playersViewController` further in your code?

Comment: Its just a help `viewController` that I want to get rid of when button is pressed. Remove it from the `superView`

Comment: how you are adding the `playersViewController`? show that code to us.

Comment: Its embedded in a `UIPageViewController`

Comment: how are you using `playersViewController`? you must be adding the view of this controller to the `customOverlay` somewhere right? add that code to your question.

Comment: @mandem112 I am agreed with @hardik. How you'r adding `playersViewController ` ?

Comment: I have added the code where I am using it

Answer (score 0):

It seems that PlayersViewController() is wrong.
You should use instantiateInitialViewController() or instantiateInitialViewController() when using StoryBoard.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistoryboard/1616214-instantiateviewcontroller

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistoryboard/1616213-instantiateinitialviewcontroller

Comment: This works but it just presents the `HomeViewCotroller` on top which is what I don't what. I just wanna press the button to make the `overlay` just disappear without presenting another  `viewController`

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain you if you are using or want to use delegate for call or implement something there is root and you have to that on a right way. You are doing well no issue but the implementation of delegate is not properly your method can't accept that so try this:-

Your Home View Controller

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController, DismissOverlayDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var customOverlay: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func dismissOverlay(_ sender: PlayersViewController) {
        self.customOverlay.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    @IBAction func go(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PlayersViewController") as! PlayersViewController
        vc.delegate = self
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true);
    }
}
```

this is your playground VC

```
protocol DismissOverlayDelegate: class {
    func dismissOverlay(_ sender: PlayersViewController)
}

class PlayersViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    weak var delegate: DismissOverlayDelegate?

    @IBAction func getStartedTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.delegate?.dismissOverlay(self)
    }

}
```

now hope you understand what you have to do...!

Comment: this looks great, but where would I use the `@IBAction func go(_ sender: UIButton) {}`. I understand instantiating it but I don't have the button go button in the `HomeViewController`

Comment: yeah I did by adding it the code that embeds the vcs into a `UIPageViewController`

Comment: can you explain exactly what you want

Comment: I have a `UIBarbuttonItem` that shows these `viewControllers` as help pages in an overlay. I have a `button` on the on the last `viewController` that I want to tap to remove it the overlay hence removing it from the `superview`

Comment: there are so many methods for removing like you can use .isHidden, stackView and hide that, or set height constraint 0 of that view so why you choose this hard method?